# Apexchart markers overflow bug

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Looking through one of the demo Apexchart I noticed this problem:

[image: demo]

The marker is not displayed correctly.

Here is a demo:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgwXrJ)

Date and time is filled with this:

```
function generateDayWiseTimeSeries(baseval, count, yrange) {
  var i = 0;
  var series = [];
  while (i < count) {
    var x = baseval;
    var y =
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (yrange.max - yrange.min + 1)) + yrange.min;

    series.push([x, y]);
    baseval += 86400000;
    i++;
  }
  return series;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug in ApexCharts which I have just [fixed](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/commit/074beb64f934210febd34313ba93d82939157721).

The patch will be released today, so hopefully, you won't have to make any changes on your side other than upgrading to 3.6.12.